# how to add corner radius and padding to multi-line spannable text

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

How can I add corner radius and padding to spannable text below ?

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
        public CustomTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFont();
        }
        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setFont();
        }
        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setFont();
        }

        private void setFont() {
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/TEXT.ttf");
            setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);

 Spannable myspan = new SpannableString(getText());
    myspan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF757593), 0, myString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txtview.setText(myspan);


        }
    }
```

Comment: I think your question could benefit a *lot* from some more details. Instead of a one-liner, could you describe the visual effect of what you're trying to achieve? Or, even better, show the desired effect with a picture/drawing?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Is what you want something like this?

[image: screenshot]

If so, you can create this with following code alone:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#999999"
          android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is what rounded_corners.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

And this is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/TEXT.ttf");

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);

        String text = "Text1\nText2\nText3";
        Spannable myspan = new SpannableString(text);
        myspan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF757593), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(myspan);
    }
}
```

I had to use different colors so that you can see it is rounded corners. You can just play with the color values. And I don't have the TEXT.ttf file so I can't know how it will look like. Above picture is of course without custom font.

Comment: the one above is easy but not what i was looking for. I am looking for the same feature on an multiline textview and the background color should only exist behind the text. ie: no color should be present if the text is pushed to the next line .

Comment: cool. basically it should be block background color.color,padding and radius should only exist behind text not behind the empty space.

Comment: radius should only behind the empty space? In that case you need a TextView with no paddings but with margins.

Comment: radius should be behind text and margin/padding before and after the text line . the image has white background around entire layout .I want it around each line and within the text.

Comment: Can you somehow show it to me? I can't really draw it on my mind. By the way if you want extra space between lines you can just use android:lineSpacingExtra attribute in TextView element.

Comment: I think you need to get rid of the Spannable object, put the color on the background xml file and use it directly for the TextView with almost no padding (5 dp should be fine). For more than one line I am afraid you need to use more than one TextView. You can put your TextViews in a ViewParent (like LinearLayout) if you need another background that wraps the whole text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89663/discussion-between-jason-and-necipallef).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Just copied from above answer, need only this.
set this as your TextView 's background, thats all.

Comment: Background color is spread over the entire layout of textview and not just the word . Basically if the textview word cannot fit in that line the background color still exists but I want the background color to exist only behind the words.